# Linq query to get value from nested object

Tags: c#, linq

I need to pull a specific value from a nested object without using a `foreach` loop. I think the right approach here is a linq query, but I'm unable to grab the  value I need. Considering the class structure:

```
public class Order
{
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public List<OrderItems> { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItems
{
    public int OrderItemID { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public List<OrderItemShipping> OrderItemShippings { get; set; } 
}

public class OrderItemShipping
{
    public int OrderItemShippingID { get; set; }
    public Address ShipAddress { get; set; }


public class Address
{
    public int AddressID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to do something like:

```
 var shipToAddress = Order.OrderItems.OrderItemShipping.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Address.Address1);
```

But my syntax must not be correct, because I'm unable to grab the value I need?

Comment: Perhaps `SelectMany` is what you are looking for?

Comment: where is your property name for type `List<OrderItems>` in the order class?

Comment: You need to have some ops in your linq like x => x.Address.Address1== "something"

Comment: You need to determine which `OrderItem` you want first, then which `OrderItemShipping` from that and finally the `Address`.

Comment: _"because I'm unable to grab the value I need"_ well, _what_ value do you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to access items of (nested) collections `SelectMany` is your friend:

```
var shipToAddress = Order.OrderItems
     .SelectMany(oi => oi.OrderItemShipping.Select(ois => ois.ShipAddress.Address1)))
     .FirstOrDefault();
```

Your syntax was wrong because the overload of `FirstOrDefault` expects a predicate(so a function that returns a `bool`) but you were passing: `FirstOrDefault(x => x.Address.Address1)`.

If you need to filter it somehow("specific value from a nested object") you need to explain your requirement  more precisely.

Comment: Thank you, this did exactly what I needed.